# Blazor Server cannot interact with components

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I've made a simple app in Blazor Server, and it works fine for the most part except for when I attempt to run it on my VPS with HTTPS. When I run the app no errors appear, and the websocket appears to connect successfully (viewed from the Firefox console), and yet I cannot interact with any of the components on the website. The websocket doesn't send over any anything when attempting to interact with the components either, but it keeps heartbeating.

I've made a brand new Blazor Server project and followed the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server, but to no avail.

The VPS runs on `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`, `Apache2` as the webserver (attemped using `nginx`, didn't help), and `Cloudflare` as the CA.
The certificate and key are correct and not outdated.

I'm running this virtual host (taken from the link above, and additionally from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0 (tried just using the configuration from the first link, didn't work)).

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName              <serverName>

        Protocols               h2 http/1.1

        ProxyRequests           On
        ProxyPreserveHost       On
        ProxyPassMatch          ^/_blazor/(.*) http://localhost:5000/_blazor/$1
        ProxyPass               /_blazor ws://localhost:5000/_blazor
        ProxyPass               / http://localhost:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse        / http://localhost:5000/

        ErrorLog                ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog               ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine               on
        SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
        SSLCompression          off
        SSLSessionTickets       on
        SSLUseStapling          off
        SSLCertificateFile      /home/cf.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /home/cf.key
        SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is how the Blazor Server main looks like (the snippet that's commented out I've tried, didn't help):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        //builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        //{
        //    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
        //    {
        //        var pem = File.ReadAllText(builder.Configuration["PemPath"]).Trim();
        //        var key = File.ReadAllText(builder.Configuration["KeyPath"]).Trim();
        //        var crt = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(pem, key);

        //        options.ServerCertificate = crt;
        //    });
        //});

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new() { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto });
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.MapBlazorHub();
        app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

        app.Run();
    }
```

To confirm: I'm able to access the website via HTTPS, the HTTPS connection is successful, no Razor component I interact with does anything.
Any help or tips on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue.
If anyone else comes by this having a similar issue, check with your CA (Cloudflare in my case) a setting called "auto-minify" (or similar) which minimizes your HTML, CSS, and Java.
The article that helped me solve my issue: https://zimmergren.net/solved-asp-net-core-blazor-web-sites-does-not-work-with-cloudflare-html-minification/